# javascript prompt - adding variable in default text

Tags: javascript, prompt

For javascript prompt:

```
prompt("Message", "default value in the text field");
```

is it possible to add a variable into the default value?

For example:

```
var default = 'default value';
prompt("Message", +default+"and other values");
```

The above example doesn't work as it shows 'NaN and other values' in the text field. I want the field to show 'default value and other values'. I'm wondering what's the right way to do it.

Comment: sounds like your variable is expecting a number and it isn't ? What should the variable contain , and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 44):

Stupid me. Here's the solution:

```
var default = 'default value';
prompt("Message", default+"and other values");
```

There was a leading plus before the default variable.

Comment: At least you've stayed positive.